# Showing just color ramp in legend without values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, legend, color-ramp

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Is there a way to show, on the legend, just the color ramp as a single patch instead of with each group of values?

I don't really need to show those values on the legend.

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

I would prefer to have it look like the ramp in the properties window and somehow note that the green area is less concern, while red is more concern.

Such as this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The way I've done it in the past is to add a *Raster* to my map, symbolise it using the Color Ramp I want, and turn the layer off in the TOC.  You can make the legend show for layers that are turned off.

Raster with Color Ramp in TOC:
[image]

Legend shows layers that are not visible:
[image]

You may need to resize the symbol in the legend.  You can do this by going into Legend Properties and opening the Legend Item properties for the raster layer.  Modify the symbol patch height.
[image]

End result is a legend showing the color ramp as desired.
[image]

You can rename the layer in your TOC to suit, and make your actual layer not show in the legend.  You can also remove values to have them not show in the legend.  To remove values just click on the value in the TOC, press F2 to rename, and delete the text.