# Adding continuous color ramp as legend using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, color-ramp

I am interested in adding a continuous color ramp legend with numerical labels like the following example to place on the layout view of arcmap:

[image]

I am quite new to arcMap so I'm not sure how I can do this. On the symbology tab, I used graduated colors with a preset color ramp from ArcMap. There are 60 classes, so when I insert a color ramp, the result becomes this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked a few years back. You can find it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230244/how-do-i-show-just-the-color-ramp-in-legend-without-values).

If you want to have breakpoints, ESRI has written a blog post about [advanced labeling](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/imagery/advanced-labeling-for-the-stretch-renderer/). It shows how to create breakpoints on the stretched renderer.